# Permission denied when upload file in java web application deployed on linux server

Tags: java, linux, spring, wildfly

I have a java web application with spring 4 and jstl deployed on wildfly installed on linux server. In this app, I have to upload Excel files to extrat data and inject the hole in some table. To do this I defined this configuration for multipart :

```
public class myAppServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
... 

private static final String TEMP_FOLDER_NAME = "tmp"; // Temporary location where files will be stored

private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5242880; // 5MB : Max file size.
// Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 20971520; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.

private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0; // Size threshold after which files will be written to disk

private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement() {
        StringBuilder uploadTempDirectoryUrl = new StringBuilder();
        uploadTempDirectoryUrl.append(System.getenv(XeryaConstants.HOME_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME)).append(File.separator)
                .append(TEMP_FOLDER_NAME);
        File tempDirectory = new File(uploadTempDirectoryUrl.toString());
        if (!tempDirectory.exists()) {
            log.info("XeryaServletInitializer - Create temp directory " + uploadTempDirectoryUrl);
            tempDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        log.info("XeryaServletInitializer - Multiplart temporal directory: " + uploadTempDirectoryUrl);
        MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(System.getenv(AppConstants.HOME_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME),
                MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
        return multipartConfigElement;
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
    }
}
```

This is the code of the method generale the error (line beetween **)

```
    public static File convert(MultipartFile file) throws IOException
{
    File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
    **convFile.createNewFile();**
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
    fos.write(file.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    return convFile;
}
```

In the linux sever, the tmp folder which is created in configuration floder out off wildfly has this credentials:

```
root@VM-XITS01-DEV:/opt/xerya_home# ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 9 wildfly wildfly 4096 juil. 25 02:21
```

The problem is when I upload the excel file from windows OS, I have this error:

```
    2018-07-25 03:06:25,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47) java.io.IOException: Permission denied
2018-07-25 03:06:25,192 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47)        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
2018-07-25 03:06:25,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47)        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
2018-07-25 03:06:25,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47)        at com.xerya.school.util.XeryaUtils.convert(XeryaUtils.java:103)
2018-07-25 03:06:25,193 ERROR [stderr] (default task-47)        at com.xerya.school.web.validator.rest.importdata.RestImportDataStudentController.uploadFile(RestImportDataStudentController.java:75)
```

Can some one help me plz to resolve this problem. In Windows all work right.

Comment: The code that you have posted is **not** the code that is failing - Please post the code for `XeryaUtils.convert` and `RestImportDataStudentController.uploadFile`

Comment: Did you try making it rwx on everything (rwxrwxrwx), not just rwxr_xr_x?

Comment: you can try with give all permison. chmod 777 -R /opt/xerya_home/

Comment: @Scary, I complete question with code generating the error. I upload the file from my windows pc and the application is deployed on linux one. When I test with the application deployed on xindows every thing is ok

Comment: do some simple debugging and let us know what the value of `file.getOriginalFilename()` is.

Answer (score 0):

I thanks every body for thiers responses.
Finally, I located the bug. It comes from this line:

```
File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
```

To resolve it, I change it by:

```
String fileName = System.getenv(XeryaConstants.HOME_ENV_VARIABLE_NAME)
            .concat(File.separator)
            .concat(TEMP_FOLDER_NAME).concat(File.separator)
            .concat(file.getOriginalFilename());
    File convFile = new File(fileName);
```

When I look to getOriginalFilename documentation, it says: "Return the original filename in the client's filesystem. This may contain path information depending on the browser used, but it typically will not with any other than Opera.

I think that this explains the behavior that I get:
When the application were deployed on windows, and I upload the file since chrome, no error was found. But when the application were deployed on linux and I upload the file from chrome the bug was found. I was fixed as I said later by concat file.getOriginalFilename() with the absolute path of the container folder.